# openCV libraries call local path that does not exist

Tags: c++, opencv

i am making a simple c++ program with openCV library included. Eclipse IDE recognises openCV commands and library locations, but when i try to build the project, compiler gives external error, referring to opencv.hpp or core.hpp file calling a "opencv2/core.hpp" path, which does not exist in opencv folder. I figured out that the problem is linked to the way core.hpp is called, but the library files are read-only. 
From what i saw in opencv.hpp file, this relative "opencv2/[module].hpp" reference is not only for the core, but all other modules as well. There is no opencv2 folder inside the one to where openCV is installed at all, in fact.

I've tried reinstalling and remaking openCV with different making arguments, using a different IDE and including direct search folders in eclipse. The problem, apparently, lies in the files themselves, or the way it maybe gets installed in the system the wrong way. The problem persists on both my main ubuntu machine and the ARMbian orange pi.

i get this error when trying to include any openCV library that contains
`#include "opencv2/[opencv module].hpp"` in it

as a result, compilation is terminated with the error message stating "/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52:28: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory"

edit 1: GCC c++ compiler options are `-Iusr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2 -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0` and linker's options are `-L/usr/local/lib`. 
The code is a simple displayImage

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

edit 2: `$ pkg-config --libs opencv` does not see openCV as installed in the system, altho i've made sure to run `make install` and `ldconfig` on the path. This may be a signal of faulty installation, but this is just a sidenote, not entirely related to main problem. I have tried reinstalls and to different folders, but this also persists as well as a main problem

Comment: would you please add your code, and your settings from properties --> C/C++ build ?

Comment: @Y.AL sure, i've updated the post.

Comment: @rerartedboi... You have to provide the path to the folder which contains the `opencv2` folder. Like this: `-I/usr/local/include/opencv4`

Comment: @sgarizvi this produced like, 620 errors and 309 warnings related to mat.hpp and mat.inl.hpp. Weird. Happily tho, error of core.hpp not being found vanished, so, it's moving somewhere i guess

Comment: w.r.t your edit2, have you verified that files lib are there ?

Comment: @Y.AL yeah, i've checked their presence through file browser and eclipse's ability to actually see and open them. They are certainly there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apparently, @sgarizvi 's comment was the answer. I just needed to set the include path to `I/usr/local/include/opencv4` and it worked. After that, the error was fixed.

I am replying to my own question to close the case, as i cannot upvote/veryfy a comment

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since your include path is `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2`
Replace the first three lines

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

by

```
#include <opencv.hpp>
#include <imgproc.hpp>
#include <highgui.hpp>
```

Comment: This way of including worked, but the main problem persisted. in opencv.hpp @ line 52 opencv2/core.hpp: no such file or dir. I think this is because opencv.hpp refers to a __relative__ folder that is lower in hierarchy, trying to find core.hpp in opencv2 folder which oCV.hpp is currently in. to clarify, it tries to find a folder it is __already__ in down the way. Not entirely sure tho, but only clue i have

Comment: inside opencv.hpp, it would be  #include "opencv2/core.hpp" , so provide only the path of opencv2 folder to GCC c++ compiler , and include inside double quotation

Comment: i did it just now, read latest comment reply on my original post. About 620 errors