# "undefined reference" and includes not found when using OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm very newbie with c++ and I need some help with libraries

Here's the case,

This simple code:

```c++
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  cv::CascadeClassifier eye_detection;
  return 1;
}
```

compiling with

```bash
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include/opencv4
```

returns me

```bash
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOsUApG.o: na função "main":
main.cpp:(.text+0x20): referência não definida para "cv::CascadeClassifier::CascadeClassifier()"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x31): referência não definida para "cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier()"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which translates to "undefined reference"

---

I also tried to change the way I wrote the "includes"

```c++
#include <opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  cv::CascadeClassifier eye_detection;
  return 1;
}
```

and compile with:

```bash
g++ main.cpp
```

and I had:

```bash
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:47:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
   47 | #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

which translates to file not found

---

I checked other similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080833/opencv-libraries-call-local-path-that-does-not-exist), but I am doing it already without success

I thought about throwing the "opencv2" folder into the "include" folder directly, but that doesn't seem right, how can I compile this code the right way?

Comment: you have not correctly added `lib` files into your project configuration

Comment: You have to include the headers and link to the libraries.

Comment: The first version of includes is right, but you need to link the libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, I created the CMakeList file as the library website says and still didn't worked, so I decided to uninstall my package from my system's package manager and installed it manually downloading the code and compiling it with cmake, and it did work now, even though I changed nothing (it might just changed the folder and I wasn't able to point it right before)

In short, cpp is way more complicated than I thought, going to check more about make and cmakes files from now on